# Run background work and return "cancellation"-closure

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, background-task

I'm quite new to Rust, so this might be quite a beginner question: Assume I want to start some async action that runs in the background and with a function call I want to stop it. The desired API looks like this:

```rust
let stop = show_loadbar("loading some data...").await;
// load data...
stop().await;
```

My code:

```
pub fn show_loadbar(text: &str) -> Box<dyn FnOnce() -> Box<dyn Future<Output=()>>>
{
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::bounded::<()>(0);
    let display = task::spawn(async move {
        while receiver.try_recv().is_err() {
            // show loadbar: xxx.await;
        }
        // cleanup: yyy.await;
    });

    // return a function which stops the load bar
    Box::new(move || {
        Box::new(async {
            sender.send(()).await;
            display.await;
        })
    })
}
```

I played around quite a lot (creating a struct instead of a function and some combinations), but finally, I always get error like this:

```
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `sender`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/terminal/loading.rs:23:24
   |
23 |           Box::new(async {
   |  ________________________^
24 | |             sender.send(()).await;
   | |             ------ `sender` is borrowed here
25 | |             display.await;
26 | |         })
   | |_________^ may outlive borrowed value `sender`
```

Given the described API, is it even possible to implement the function like this in Rust?
Independent of this, what is the Rust-way to do it? Maybe this interface is absolutely not how it should be done in Rust.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error you see can be fixed by changing `async` to `async move`, so that it captures `sender` by value instead of by reference. But trying tu use your code reveals futher issues:

- you can't (and probably don't need to) await `show_loadbar()`, since it's not itself async.
- pin the boxed future to be able to await it.
- a bounded `async_std` channel cannot have the capacity of 0 (it panics if given 0);
- handle the error returned by `sender.send()`, e.g. by unwrapping it.
- (optionally) get rid of the outer box by returning `impl FnOnce(...)` instead of `Box<dyn FnOnce(...)>`.

With these taken into account, the code would look like this:

```
pub fn show_loadbar(_text: &str) -> impl FnOnce() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::bounded::<()>(1);
    let display = task::spawn(async move {
        while receiver.try_recv().is_err() {
            // show loadbar: xxx.await;
        }
        // cleanup: yyy.await;
    });

    // return a function which stops the load bar
    || {
        Box::pin(async move {
            sender.send(()).await.unwrap();
            display.await;
        })
    }
}

// usage example:
async fn run() {
    let cancel = show_loadbar("xxx");
    task::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    cancel().await;
}

fn main() {
    task::block_on(run());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well and I even had the chance to learn / google `std::pin::Pin` (I did not know that before). Thx:)!